# Getting chrome.exe popup opened while executing selenium scripts

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting a popup opened from location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\application\chrome.exe while executing selenium webdriver scripts in chrome browser.

This one is throwing the error as session timed out.

Note: The same codebase is working fine in other machine.

Can you please help me out to get this sorted.

The code I am using is as below:-

```
var arr = new string[7] {
    "--start-maximized", "--ignore-certificate-errors", "--disable-popup-blocking", "--disable-default-apps", "--auto-launch-at-startup", "--always-authorize-plugins", "--user-agent= " + FrameGlobals.userAgentValue
};
chromeCapabilities.AddArguments(arr);

WebDriverObj = new ChromeDriver(chromeCapabilities);
```

This is how i'm initiating the chrome browser. not mentioning any version inside codebase.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi8D5.png)

Thanks in advance.
Hema

Comment: Check the versions of Chrome you use in Webdriver, and the one that is actually installed. I've had similar issue, and it helped.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dmitry!!  
var arr = new string[7] { "--start-maximized", "--ignore-certificate-errors", "--disable-popup-blocking", "--disable-default-apps", "--auto-launch-at-startup", "--always-authorize-plugins", "--user-agent= " + FrameGlobals.userAgentValue };                                    chromeCapabilities.AddArguments(arr);
WebDriverObj = new ChromeDriver(chromeCapabilities);
This is how i'm initiating the chrome browser. not mentioning any version inside codebase. Can you please mention where it is ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add all your argument one by one and then pass it to the Chromedriver as below:-

```
        WebDriver driver=null;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./src//lib//chromedriver");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("test-type");
        options.addArgument("--start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
        options.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
        capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary","./src//lib//chromedriver");
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

Replace your argument with above-mentioned arguments

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: i tried as you mentioned but it is still opening the exe popup and the browser is not performing any actions. Have attached the screenshot for reference in the post.

Comment: I have `In order to provide you with better service, we use cookies on our pages. By using this site, you agree to our Cookies Policy.` slidding popup while launching my site but unable to disabled that while launching using chromedriver.